# freshly built Ubuntu executable fails with "Invalid argument" (exit code 126)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, linker, elf

I've compiled and built a C++ program (that uses SDL2, in case that matters) on Ubuntu 20.0.4, but when I try to run it, it just prints "Invalid argument".  If I try to run it via gdb, it also prints "Invalid argument" and then "During startup program exited with code 126."  (This before it hits a breakpoint set at `main`.)

Things I have tried:

- Verified that the execute bit is set on the file.
- Added the -no-pie linker flag, which makes it build a normal ELF executable rather than a relocatable one (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911538)).  `readelf` and `file` now both agree it is an executable.  `file` now prints:

> ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=432e038be2c1180ec019b585ffbca182a80f6c55, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped

- Checked its library dependencies with `ldd`.  A couple dozen libraries are listed but all appear to be found successfully.
- Tried executing it via `sudo`, in case it was some weird ownership/permission problem.  Same error occurs.

My Makefile is pretty simple, but it ends up doing the whole compile & link process with just this one command:

```
gcc -no-pie -o Build/soda src/*.cpp src/editline/complete.c src/editline/editline.c src/editline/sysunix.c src/MiniScript/*.cpp src/compiledData/*.c -Isrc -Isrc/editline -Isrc/MiniScript -Isrc/compiledData -lstdc++ -lm -lSDL2_image -lSDL2
```

Nothing funny here that I can see, except maybe for `-no-pie` which I mentioned above (without it, I get the same result but `file` sees it is a shared library).

I'm out of ideas.  Googling "invalid argument" doesn't work very well, but the few relevant hits I have found suggest that it's a generic error message for any failure to execute a file: wrong architecture, wrong file type, etc.  But since I have literally just built it on this very machine, it's hard to see how those could apply.

What else can I do to pin down what is causing this failure?

Comment: Why not g++ (not gcc) if you're compiling c++ code?

Comment: "Why not g++" — unless I'm mistaken, g++ is the same thing as gcc with a couple extra arguments.  My project contains a couple of .c files as well, which I need to be compiled as C, not C++, so I use gcc.

Comment: One of the arguments you're passing to your program when you run it is presumably invalid. Or it's a poor choice of error message when not passing an argument that's mandatory.

Comment: Or the program itself calls a function that returns that error code because of how it's called, and the error gets reported. Would need a [mcve] to tell anything for sure.

Comment: Compiling with debugging symbols (`gcc -g ...`) might help get more information when running it in a debugger.

Comment: @JoeStrout They are not the same, `gcc` does not link the C++ standard library. But you link it manually so it should not matter.

Comment: "Or the program itself calls a function that returns that error code" — if that were the case, I would expect gdb with a breakpoint on `main` would hit that breakpoint.  But it does not; it fails, as far as I can tell, before ever executing any code.

Comment: "gcc -g might help" — good thought.  But it doesn't change the behavior at all; it still fails with "Invalid argument" and "code 126" before hitting a breakpoint on `main`.

Comment: I suspect that one of the libraries it's soft-linking to has an invalid architecture or something.  How would I verify that or pin down which one is the problem?

Comment: The "Invalid argument" message is probably being printed by `perror`, so you  might try putting a breakpoint in that to see where it is called from.

Comment: OK, I backed up and tried a trivial "Hello world" main.cpp, compiled with `gcc main.cpp -o test -lstdc++ -lm`.  It also fails in the same way.  So SDL was a red herring.  `ldd` shows only a handful of libraries, all x86_64.  `gcc -v` shows it's configured to build x86_64-linux-gnu.  Clearly my environment is messed up somehow, but how?

Comment: Found a suggestion to try running it with strace.  This produces (on a trivial C program compiled to a.out with gcc): `execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7fff979e4af0 /* 49 vars */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`    ...a clue, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally stumbled upon the answer.  I was working in a Parallels shared folder, i.e. a folder from the host OS (macOS, in this case) which has been mounted as a drive in the Linux file system (of the Parallels virtual machine).

Apparently, running any executable from such a shared folder simply does not work.  Copying the same executable to my Linux home directory, and running it from there, works fine.  Conversely if I build a program in my Linux directory (where it works fine), and then copy it to a shared folder and try to run it from there, I get the "Invalid argument" error.

Many thanks to all who attempted to help, and I hope the next poor sap who runs into this gotcha finds this question.